# Is there a limit on pinned taskbar items?

Tags: windows-10

I just upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 10, and there seems to be a limitation on the number of items I can add to the "pinned list" for taskbar items:

[image]

Before I upgraded, my list of pinned items was significantly larger. Once I upgraded, it just chose to display the first 12 of the items that were formerly pinned there in Windows 7.

If I unpin an item in the Pinned list, it does then allow me to pin another one, but I'm still stuck at a max of 12 pinned items.

**Is there any way to pin more than 12 items to the list?** I have a lot of machines I need to remote into, and being able to pin them all is a big time-saver.

Comment: It looks like you use Remote Desktop a LOT. While this is not the question asked, you might find a program like [mRemoteNG](http://www.mremoteng.org) or [Terminals](https://terminals.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Features%20and%20Screen%20shots) better for you anyway.

Comment: of interest, the reg key mentioned in http://blogs.technet.com/b/win7/archive/2011/05/10/change-the-number-of-recent-items-displayed-in-windows-7-jump-list.aspx no longer exists, and adding it doesn't seem to change behaviour. Also the UI for changing this through taskbar / start list Properties is gone.

Comment: Really bad I can not answer this question and get credits for the effort. The answer is: yes there is a way. regedit and insert dword 32 bit in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced named JumpListItems_Maximum and set value eg. to 19 (23).

Comment: see http://superuser.com/a/1068133/397702

Comment: If I have more than 10 additional Reputation I can post the answer here, I believe.

Comment: @gReX I tried your solution mentioned in the other post (add the reg key) and it worked for me. Now that you have the necessary rep, post the relevant part of your other answer here (a lot of the rest of the answer didn't apply) and I'll mark it as the solution

Comment: Tanks, but unfortunately, association bonus does not count.Feel free, to answer your question yourself. This could help other. Reputation is not so important and I'm more helpful on stackoverflow.

Comment: btw, any Idea why someone voted mit down here: http://superuser.com/a/1068133/397702

Comment: @gReX the formatting/readabilty of that answer is *pretty* bad. Sometimes you gotta prettify your answers

Comment: @gReX The moderators [removed the protection](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/114/conversation/lift-protection-for-grex) on this question so that you can post an answer. (And my rep is too low to see any info on downvotes on that other question)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you increase the size of a jumplist, the number of pinnable items on that jumplist increases accordingly. To increase the size of all jumplists (and thereby increase the maximum number of pinnable items):

1. Open regedit
2. Browse to the following key

   `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced`
3. Add a new DWORD (32-bit) entry named `JumpListItems_Maximum`
4. Set the value of `JumpListItems_Maximum` to the number of items you want to see in your jumplists (e.g., 19 (if hex) or 25 (if decimal))

Alternatively, you can make the registry change by saving the following text into a file named `jumpList.reg` and then importing it into the registry using **File > Import...** within regedit:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced]
"JumpListItems_Maximum"=dword:00000017
```

Sometimes the change takes effect immediately, but if not, don't forget to restart/new login!

Answer (score 7):

You can only have up to 12 pinned items on any program.

What I suggest is making a folder with all the icons [RDP files] to the machines and pin it as a toolbar:

1. Create a folder named `Remote Desktop` (can be any name)
2. Right click on empty space on taskbar
3. Select Toolbars
4. Click `New Toolbar`
5. Locate to the folder and select it

(I suggest you keep them more organized, however.)

[image]
My pinned folder is the programs folder.

Comment: in my particular case it's not RDP entries but folders for the pinned Windows Explorer icon. How would that change this answer?

Comment: You would just put the `folders for the pinned Windows Explorer icon` into a folder then use that folder as a toolbar. Now, let me find out how to access them...

Comment: Can you update this before the bounty expires?

Comment: I will try & ask this question here...

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/995983/how-can-i-view-all-items-pinned-to-a-programs-jump-list-on-windows-10

Comment: see the above regedit solution - I just upped mine to 25 and it worked like a champ. I currently have 14 pinned and the rest in the recent list

Answer (score -1):

Couldn't a software like [MRemoteNG](http://www.mremoteng.org/) fully solve your problems ?  It stores the number of sessions you want (RDP, but also SSH or other protocols) and is pretty handy to use.
It would only take one slot in your taskbar, and let you navigate among your sessions using tabs.

I know it doesn't really answer the initial question, but I'm not sure the title really describes your problem, since you seem to have found the limit of 12 pinned items you were asking about, but don't mention your real need : more than 12 shortcuts at once for your RDP sessions.

Hope this helps.

Comment: RDP was just an example. I use the Pinned list for at least a dozen other programs that I dock to the Taskbar, so my question has a broader relevance than just RDP.