# How can I view all items pinned to a program's jump list on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

Is there any location where I can see all the pinned items on a jump list? For example, if I pin a bunch of locations to the remote desktop app, can I view the whole list in explorer?

EDIT:
Let's say I have links of sites pinned to chrome (`MUST work with any application, not just chrome`), How would I extract the contents of the pinned sites of the jump list? I'm looking for a native or script way to do this, but software is fine too.

Comment: The solution doesn't need explorer.exe, but a way to copy and paste the files.

Answer (score 1):

Per [this post](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/9601-jump-lists-back-up-restore-windows-8-a.html) you can get to them through shell:Recent\AutomaticDestinations and Shell:Recent\CustomDestinations.

The post also has batch files to export and import.

I confirmed this works exporting from Windows 8.1 and importing to Windows 10. 
Note however that Windows 10 limits the number of pinned items when you could change this in Windows 8.1.

Comment: not sure, why someone downvoted the posts here. See mine to overcome the windows 10 limitation of pinned items.

Comment: @gReX Your solution did work for me on Windows 10. Thanks! My current rep won't let me upvote your answer or add a comment to your post. Wanted to point out that instead of a full restart, you can just restart Windows Explorer process from the task manager for the change to take effect. Just right-click on it in the processes tab and choose restart.

Answer (score -1):

Tools I found to read the Jumplists are:

[jump list view](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/jump_lists_view.html)
with a lot of information, a commandline mode, but need a licenze for commerzial use

[Windows LNK Parsing Utility (lp)](https://tzworks.net/prototype_page.php?proto_id=11) working out of the box as freeware

The "pinned" part ist still missing, but as bgstill points out, you have to watch Shell:Recent\CustomDestinations

I don't get it running via Code. What I miss ist the Encoding of the Jump-Lists, and how to decode with easy code. Look at the answer from bkstill, that looks good. My research so far:

Jump-Lists are stored in

```
%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations
```

The files there are [Structured Storage-Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380369%28VS.85%29.aspx). A read-Write excample found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380387(v=vs.85).aspx)

===

For my purpose it was enough, to increase the number of the pinnable Items by increasing the number of Jumplistitems for all lists:

regedit and insert dword 32 bit in

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced
```

named `JumpListItems_Maximum` and set value eg. to 19 (23).

Or save as jumpList.reg and import:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced]
"JumpListItems_Maximum"=dword:00000017
```

Don't miss the restart!

Comment: ok, more help for this http://superuser.com/q/947525/397702 but I will update my answer, If I make any Progress. It is somewhere in the registry, but I think that the List is encrypted.

Comment: At HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced JumpListItems_Maximum doesn't exist, & if I create it, it doesn't make the pinned list any bigger.  So this is not a solution that works for me for Windows 10.

Microsoft support says this pinned list can't be made larger.  http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start/windows-10-jump-list/44f27211-2647-43bc-816d-9ca3aa8e97d0

I suspect they think that for touch screen it must be that way, but they could still make it expand horizontally as well as vertically, and they should have.

Comment: The link you provided suggest the same solution to increase the jumplist-Items. With increased Jumplists you can pin more Items. The solution works fine. May you miss a restart?

Comment: @Eliptical View My provided Solution to increase the jumplist work .